# How can I find which two rows have timestamps closest to each other?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a web application for location-based check ins, sort of like a local 4square, but based on RFID tags.

Anyway, each check-in is stored in a MySQL table with a userID and the time of the check-in as a DATETIME column.

Now I'd like to show which users have the closest check-in times between different stations.

Explanation: Let's say user A checked in at 21:43:12 and then again at 21:43:19. He moved between stations in 7 seconds.

There are thousands of check-ins in the database, how do I write SQL to select the users with the two closest check-in times?

Comment: For *fast* lookup you need to precalculate time to previous checkin and store it somewhere

Comment: Do you just want the user ids?  Or do you want the associated timestamps as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really fast solution would introduce some precalculations. Like storing the difference between current and previous checkins.

In this case you would select what you need in fast manner (as long as you cover that column by index).

Not using precalculation in this case would cause terrible queries that would operate over cartesian-like productions.

Comment: I guess I could calculate and store the time difference between each user's check-in with each row. Is that what you mean?

Comment: hey mate, can you do me a favour and have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790402/pdo-refuses-to-delete-a-row-of-data-in-specific-table) of mine? It has me stumped like a bastard :(

Comment: @MånsJonasson.  Not really. You would calculate the difference only between **subsequent** checkins of the same userid. That means you would add a new column to the checkin table: `difference`. Each time you insert a new checkin, you would select the last checkin of the same userid and you would calculate the difference to the data to the last checkin.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select
    a.id,
    b.id,
    abs(a.rfid-b.rfid)
from
    table1 a,
    table1 a
where
    a.userID=b.userID
    // and any other conditions to make it a single user
group by
    a.id,
    b.id,
    a.rfid,
    b.rfid
order by
    abs(a.rfid-b.rfid) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Doing a cross product for each user will scale very badly indeed.  How would this compare to using correlated sub-queries?

Comment: `abs(a.rfid-b.rfid)` would return unpredictable result as long as both columns don't participate in `group by` and there is no aggregate function

Comment: Thanks, translated to my row names it looks like this:

    select
     a.id,
     b.id,
        a.uid,
        b.uid,
        abs(a.dateWhen-b.dateWhen)
    from
    rfid_actions a,
    rfid_actions b
where
    a.uid=b.uid
group by
    a.uid,
    b.uid
order by
    abs(a.dateWhen-b.dateWhen) desc
limit 1

But the results are strange:
id      id(2)   uid             uid(2)          abs(a.date...
394 394 6a42c540 6a42c540 0.000000

(dang it, I don't get the stackoverflow markdown yet)

Comment: And now the the whole `group by` clause makes no sense. Why to `group by` if you only use groupped columns?

Comment: @zerkms There is probably no point in returning both RFID times, but if you say that the `abs()` will give bad results unless they are grouped by, I trust you. The query will return a syntax error unless non aggregate columns are grouped by.

Comment: @Fluffeh: right. But if you remove `group by` - what would change? Nothing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Have you looked at DATEDIFF
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Cheers
--Jocke

Comment: 1. It's mysql, not sql server 2. not an answer

Answer (score 0):

First, you want an index on the user and then the timestamp.

Second, you need to use correlated sub-queries to find "the next timestamp".

Then you use GROUP BY to find the smallest interval per user.

```
SELECT
  a.user_id,
  MIN(TIMEDIFF(b.timestamp, a.timestamp)) AS min_duration,
FROM
  checkin      AS a
INNER JOIN
  checkin      AS b
    ON  b.user_id   = a.user_id
    AND b.timestamp = (SELECT MIN(timestamp)
                         FROM checkin
                        WHERE user_id   = a.user_id
                          AND timestamp > a.timestamp)
GROUP BY
  a.user_id
ORDER BY
  min_duration
LIMIT
  1
```

If you want to allow for multiple users with the same `min_duration`, I recommend storing the results *(without the `LIMIT 1`)* in a temporary table, then searching that table for all users that share the minimum duration.

Depending on the volume of data, this could be slow.  One optimisation would be to cache the results of the `TIMEDIFF()`.  Every time a new checkin is recorded, also calculate and store the duration since the last checkin, maybe using triggers.  Having this pre-calculated makes the query simpler and the values indexable.

Answer (score 0):

I figure, you only want to compute the difference between two checkins if, they are two consecutive checkins of the same person.

```
create table test (
id int,
person_id int,
checkin datetime);

insert into test (id, person_id, checkin) values (1, 1, now());
insert into test (id, person_id, checkin) values (2, 1, now());
insert into test (id, person_id, checkin) values (3, 2, now());
insert into test (id, person_id, checkin) values (4, 2, now());
insert into test (id, person_id, checkin) values (5, 1, now());
insert into test (id, person_id, checkin) values (6, 2, now());
insert into test (id, person_id, checkin) values (7, 1, now());


select * from (
  select a.*,
  (select a.checkin - b.checkin
    from test b where b.person_id = a.person_id
    and b.checkin < a.checkin
    order by b.checkin desc
    limit 1
  ) diff
  from test a 
  where a.person_id = 1
  order by a.person_id, a.checkin
  ) tt
where diff is not null
order by diff asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM table_name AS a
JOIN table_name AS b
ON a.id != b.id
ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.checkin, b.checkin) ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Should do it. Might be a bit laggy as mentioned.